# Export SVN dir from one repository and commit to another one

Tags: svn

We have an SVN repository which is stored online with all our tickets, wikis, etc. For deployment purposes, we need to use a second SVN repository on which we have no control: we cannot use svndump, svnload, svnsync, etc. We can update and commit basically.

At deployment time, I would like to export a working copy from Dev Repo and then commit it to Staging+Live repo. Please see following sketch for a rough idea of what I need to do.

[image: SVN Workflow]

Is there an SVN command doing just that? I could use the svn export command but then I would have to add all new files by hand I believe. Also, I would like to avoid to export all the files when only few changed. So I would like to avoid recreating the S working copy each time I want to deploy the site.

Or maybe there is a much simpler solution?

Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest this approach:

- create a working copy via `svn co s+l_repo` (initial checkout, can be done manually)
- export your dev repo via `svn export` into this working copy, overwriting all files in it
- add all new files via `svn add --force`
- commit your working copy to s+l repo

Easily scripted, and you can run it via a batch job every night.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if I export, I will transfer all files while only a few changed. We actually have a lot of files which do not change from one version to another...

Comment: I was talking about the export process. It will reexport all the files each time I deploy. This can take some time... However, this is just for optimization purposes and would not be a big deal. But if we could just export the modified files then commit them, it would be perfect. Not sure if it is possible though.